# DAX Group By DateDiff Segments

Tags: dax

I am writing a DAX query for use in SSRS dataset.

I have a requirement to calculate the date difference between a dimension date column and today(), then group these into segments, I.e. 1-7 days, 7-10 days etc - and return the segment for each row in the table (with other additional filters)

As it’s for use in SSRS I’m using EVALUATE(SUMMARIZECOLUMNS

A switch statement won’t work for value ranges in DAX and when I use nested If statement the query uses all available memory.

Is there a function I can use for to group by the calculated column into segments.

Any advise appreciated.

Thanks
W

Comment: Do you have a specific list of segments? Are they just broken into weeks?

Comment: Hi, I don’t have the list in front of me but number of weeks would be a great start if you have  any advice, thanks

Comment: why not just create a calculated column to store the datediff and then a switch statement to group the results?

Comment: I have limited control over the ssas model - but I will try this option - as seems simplest to do it there rather than in dax

Comment: "A switch statement won’t work for value ranges in DAX" - could you please explain what you mean by that? I use it often, not sure why you can't.